# Copying from one sheet pasting to another sheet without using the clipboard, always needs to paste in the first empty row.Getting error 424

Tags: excel, runtime-error, clipboard, vba

I keep getting run time error 424, it seems to not be able to work out the number of used rows in column A of `wsy1`, I am using the same technique for `wsx1`. It keeps saying that `lRows2 = 0` when it should actually be `5`. I cant seem to work out why it is doing that, Please help!

```vb
Sub Import_CSV()
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lCols As Long
    Dim lRows2 As Long
    Dim lCols2 As Long
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim wsc1 As Worksheet
    Dim wsx1 As Worksheet
    Dim wsy1 As Worksheet
    Dim sizex As Long
    Dim sizey As Long
    Dim DRows As Long
    Dim DCols As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Matlab\R2006b\work\INCALogCommentList v01\LogFileComments.csv")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Matlab\R2006b\work\INCALogCommentList v01\MeasurementDatabase.xlsx")
    Set wsx1 = Workbooks("LogFileComments").Worksheets("LogFileComments")
    Set wsy1 = Workbooks("MeasurementDatabase.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsy2 = Workbooks("MeasurementDatabase.xlsx").Worksheets("Signal List")
    Set wsc1 = Workbooks("Book1 (Autosaved) (Autosaved)").Worksheets("Comparison Sheet Final")

    wsx1.Columns(2).TextToColumns , _
    Destination:=wsx1.Range("B1"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:="|", _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=False

    'Now, copy what you want from x:
    lRows = wsx1.Cells(wsx1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lCols = wsx1.Cells(1, wsx1.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column

    Set rng1 = wsx1.Range(wsx1.Cells(1, 1), wsx1.Cells(lRows, lCols))
    rng1.copy

    sizex = rng1.Columns.Count
    sizey = rng1.Rows.Count
    DRows = sizey + lRows2
    DCols = sizex

    lRows2 = wsy1.Cells(wsy1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row.Offset(1)

    Set rng2 = wsy1.Range(wsy1.Cells(lRows2, 1), wsy1.Cells(DRows, DCols))
    rng2.Value = rng1.Value

    'Close x:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    x.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    For Each cell In Range("A1:AD50000")
    If cell.Value = "Pre-trigger Time: 20[s]" Then
    cell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
     End If
     Next cell

    'close y

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    y.Save
    y.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the offset on the end of your lrows2 assignment?

lRows2 = wsy1.Cells(wsy1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row.**Offset**

Comment: Because the assignment points to the last used row, so I need to go down one to the first empty row. (btw in the script I have it as Offset(1), I don't know why it didn't show on the post).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointer, it turns out the offset was confusing things, I have used a lRows2 + 1 instead! Thanks!

The code below works for any interested parties!

```html
Sub Import_CSV()
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lCols As Long
Dim lRows2 As Long
Dim lCols2 As Long
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim wsc1 As Worksheet
Dim wsx1 As Worksheet
Dim wsy1 As Worksheet
Dim sizex As Long
Dim sizey As Long
Dim DRows As Long
Dim DCols As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Matlab\R2006b\work\INCALogCommentList v01\LogFileComments.csv")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Matlab\R2006b\work\INCALogCommentList v01\MeasurementDatabase.xlsx")
Set wsx1 = Workbooks("LogFileComments").Worksheets("LogFileComments")
Set wsy1 = Workbooks("MeasurementDatabase").Worksheets("Measurement Info Sheet")
Set wsy2 = Workbooks("MeasurementDatabase").Worksheets("Measurement Signal List - SPA")
Set wsc1 = Workbooks("Book1 (Autosaved) (Autosaved)").Worksheets("Comparison Sheet Final")

wsx1.Columns(2).TextToColumns , _
Destination:=wsx1.Range("B1"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
Other:=True, _
OtherChar:="|", _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=False

'Now, copy what you want from x:
lRows = wsx1.Cells(wsx1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lCols = wsx1.Cells(1, wsx1.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column

Set rng1 = wsx1.Range(wsx1.Cells(1, 1), wsx1.Cells(lRows, lCols))
rng1.copy

sizex = rng1.Columns.Count
sizey = rng1.Rows.Count
lRows2 = wsy1.Cells(wsy1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
DRows = sizey + lRows2
DCols = sizex

Set rng2 = wsy1.Range(wsy1.Cells(lRows2 + 1, 1), wsy1.Cells(DRows, DCols))
rng2.Value = rng1.Value

'Close x:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
x.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


For Each cell In wsy1.Range("A1:AD50000")
If cell.Value = "Pre-trigger Time: 20[s]" Then
cell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
 End If
 Next cell
 
'close y

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
y.Save
y.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```